# nginx client_max_body_size is not working correctly

Tags: node.js, nginx, centos, axios, formidable

I am trying to upload file, when the api called directly it works fine, but when it is behind proxy it does not, I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy

NGINX -v
nginx version: nginx/1.15.0

also 1.17 tested and the same
OS: CentOS 7.0

Even though I'm setting client_max_body_size 30M in http block the ajax request gets cancelled on chrome network monitor!

Forntend: React, axios is used

Backend: nodejs 10

I tried to put the max size in http, server or location and the same without anyresponse.

Am I missing something here?

http settings:

```
http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

client_body_in_file_only clean;
client_body_buffer_size 32K;
client_max_body_size 30M;


keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_server_name;
    return 301 https://my_server_name;
}
server {

listen 443 ssl default_server;
server_name my_server_name;
ssl_certificate     path_to_cert;
ssl_certificate_key path_to_key;
root  path_to_build;
index index.html index.htm;

client_body_in_file_only clean;
client_body_buffer_size 32K;
client_max_body_size 30M;

location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003/api/;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_cache                off;

client_body_in_file_only clean;
client_body_buffer_size 32K;
client_max_body_size 30M;

}
location / {

            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Also removed client_body_in_file_only & client_body_buffer_size and still the same

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer because of slow internet connection I just increased the timeout and the problem is fixed!